# Cannot buy apps in Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps, google-checkout

I recently made an Android Application for a company and today they ordered 10 tablets (Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 3G GT-P5100) with my application. I created a Gmail Account for each Tablet and updated the software and I bought the first copy of my app with a credit card (it was succesfull and everything went perfect). When I tried to buy another copy of my app with the second Tablet I get this error:

[image: Google Play Error]

I tested all my 8 Tablets, used another Credit Card, another internet connection (3G) but I wasn't able to buy my own application! I even tried to buy Fruit Ninja and I still get the same error.

The error is in dutch, this is the translated version:

> A technical problem occurs.
>
> We can not complete the purchase process because of a technical
>   problem.
>
> Details of the problem:
>
> We cannot process this request. Any charges will automaticly be
>   canceled in 24 hours. Try it again in 24 hours

I am very confused, I recently bought a few apps for my own. I think it's because I used the same credit card for multiple Google Checkout Accounts but I don't think that's the only problem (I tried another credit card). I even called my Credit Card company and they said Google didn't even charged me when the transaction failed so the problem cannot be my Credit Card.

Comment: Have you contacted Google? Seems like that might be more fruitful since the "technical error" message implies an issue on their end (maybe their payment system went down or something).

Comment: I was wondering if someone has the same issues, I'll also will contact Google for this problem